# Why does it take a long time to compile when a tuple of a struct is held by another struct?

Tags: swift

### Environment

PC: MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)
Xcode: Version 13.0

### Details

For example, the following code takes about 3 seconds to build on average.

```
struct Foo {
    let num: Int = 0
}

struct Demo1 {
    let foos = (Foo(), Foo(), Foo(), Foo(), Foo(),
                Foo(), Foo(), Foo(), Foo(), Foo())
}

struct Demo2 {
    let foos = (Demo1(), Demo1(), Demo1(), Demo1(), Demo1(),
                Demo1(), Demo1(), Demo1(), Demo1(), Demo1())
}

struct Demo3 {
    let foos = (Demo2(), Demo2(), Demo2(), Demo2(), Demo2(),
                Demo2(), Demo2(), Demo2(), Demo2(), Demo2())
}

struct Demo4 {
    let foos = (Demo3(), Demo3(), Demo3(), Demo3(), Demo3(),
                Demo3(), Demo3(), Demo3(), Demo3(), Demo3())
}
```

On the other hand, if you replace struct with class, the average time is about 0.4 seconds.

```
struct Foo {
    let num: Int = 0
}

struct Demo1 {
    let foos = (Foo(), Foo(), Foo(), Foo(), Foo(),
                Foo(), Foo(), Foo(), Foo(), Foo())
}

class Demo2 {
    let foos = (Demo1(), Demo1(), Demo1(), Demo1(), Demo1(),
                Demo1(), Demo1(), Demo1(), Demo1(), Demo1())
}

class Demo3 {
    let foos = (Demo2(), Demo2(), Demo2(), Demo2(), Demo2(),
                Demo2(), Demo2(), Demo2(), Demo2(), Demo2())
}

class Demo4 {
    let foos = (Demo3(), Demo3(), Demo3(), Demo3(), Demo3(),
                Demo3(), Demo3(), Demo3(), Demo3(), Demo3())
}
```

Why does the difference between struct and class make a difference?
I would appreciate any advice on the cause.

Comment: May be because in the second case you have list of pointers (class objects) and in the first case list of structure, so the compiler may have to compute the total structures contained in each structure. With structs the final object is large, with classes the final object is much much smaller.

Comment: I also supposed that Foo / For in first case is a typo error.

Comment: @PtitXav
Thanks for pointing out the typo! I've fixed it!

And thanks for the comment about the difference between classes and structs!
I'll think about it some more.

Comment: Copied my post as answer

Answer (score 2):

Because in the second case you have list of pointers (class objects) and in the first case list of structure, so the compiler will have to compute the total structures contained in each structure. With structs the final object is large, with classes the final object is much much smaller.

Comment: Totally agreed, just thinking at how the size grows almost exponentially, the `Demo4` struct ending up with something similar to a 10k sized tuple..

Comment: Why would the size of the resulting data structure impact the amount of time required to compile it? The classes in this case are larger than the struct in any case (they require reference counting overhead; the struct is only one Int long).

Comment: @RobNapier it's about computing the size of the variable/property - with classes any variable of that type has stable size (8 bytes, or 4 bytes, depending on the platform). Value types, on the other hand, are stored "inline", which forces the computer to calculate in advance the space needed, and this needs to be done in a recursive manner. This is why we can't have recursive structs/enums, because their size would be infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on implicit typing. That just yanks the compiler's chain. You know the type of each variable so *declare* that type and watch compile times get much shorter!

Comment: No, it doesn't, it's not caused by type inference.

Comment: See the other answer for the real cause of the compile time difference.

Comment: @Cristik When I test this with matt's suggestion (adding explicit types), struct is just as fast as class. Why don't you believe it's caused by type inference? (Though I'm not clear why the type inference doesn't impact classes. Perhaps it doesn't decide how large the type is in the same way?)

Comment: @RobNapier the compiler performance in regards to type inference dated in Swift 1, 2, and got a lot improved along the years. Also, here we're talking about tuples of 10 elements, which is less than the problematic collection size in the old times.  And I also just tested this, and didn't see  compile time improvements when specifying the types for all the tuples.

Comment: I tested with `swiftc` v1.26.9 (the one with XC 13.0 beta 5) and exactly reproduced the OP's timings. ~3s vs ~1/2s. I know it's gotten better; I mean this specific code seems to have the problem the OP says. When I add the explicit type on `foos`, the problem goes away, just as matt suggests.

Comment: Interesting, @RobNapier, on my Intel macbook it's 15s vs. 0.3s, and there are no improvements with the type inference code. I'm using a different toolchain, though, the one part of the released Xcode 13.0.